# How to detect data beyond certain value out of a fixed range

Tags: c

I've written a c program which can read a text file with single column of data. All the data can be read into the program with the following codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

main()
{
    char temp[20];
    float t;
    int a = 0, x = 0; //a is no. of data greater than 180 and x is no of data

    FILE *fpt;

    fpt = fopen("case i.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fpt, "%s", temp);    // read and display the column header
    printf("%s\n", temp);

    while (fscanf(fpt, "%f", &t) == 1)
    {
        printf("%.2f\n", t);
        ++x;                 //count for number of data

        if (t > 180) {
          ++a;               //count for number of data > 180
        }

        if (x > 2 && a == 2) {    //place where bug is expected to occur
          printf("2 out of 3 in a row is greater than 180");
          a=0;    //reset a back to zero
          x=0;
        }     
    }

    fclose(fpt);
    system("pause");
}
```

The problem comes when I want to detect like **2 out of 3** data are **beyond 180** degree Celsius. I tried some ideas like when (**no. of data > 2**) and (**two data > 180**) then generate an error message, but it will have bug as it may have **two data > 180** but when **4 data are read**, that means it become **2 out of 4**, not **2 out of 3**, is it possible to be programmed? Thank you in advance for every help.

The following is the sample data and output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us your code. The program above does nothing but read and display the file.

Comment: Anything is possible to be programmed, but not from your description. Can you provide a sample of the data from your text file? Can you also clairify the condition you're looking for? You say "`2 out of 3`" so that's in 3 consecutive samples 2 must be over the value 180?

Comment: @Mike ya 2 out of 3 consecutive samples, my data is just a column with the temperature value like 120, 140, 197, 197, 165, 132, 127, 200, 210,....in this case the set ...,140,197, 197 are sample of 2 out of 3 is greater than 180

Comment: @MichaelWalz I've edited the code with something I tried, but I know it will have bug, how could I program to debug it ya

Comment: First of all format your code. Bugs are much easier to find with correctly formatted code.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I've added some comments and hopefully it can explain better for my condition to be looking for. thank you

Comment: @green: I just have edited your question and formatted the code. Correctly formatted code is **very** important. Look at lurker's answer below, that looks promising. Your question is somewhat iddicult to understand, add an example of your "case i.txt" file and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to keep a "sliding window" of 3 values indicating how many are over 180.

So one approach would be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char temp[20];
    float t;

    const int min_over = 2;
    const int max_window = 3;
    const int max_value = 180;
    char over[max_window];      // a 1 means over, 0 otherwise
    int oi = 0;
    int num_values = 0;

    FILE *fpt;

    fpt = fopen("case i.txt", "r");

    fscanf(fpt, "%s", temp);    // read and display the column header
    printf("%s\n", temp);

    memset(over, 0, max_window);

    while (fscanf(fpt, "%f", &t) == 1)
    {
        int num_hit, i;

        printf("%.2f\n", t);

        // Calculate num_hit: how many over in a window of max_window
        //
        over[oi] = (t > max_value) ? 1 : 0;

        if (++oi >= max_window)
            oi = 0;

        for ( num_hit = i = 0; i < max_window; i++ ) num_hit += over[i];

        // Only check for min_over/max_window after at least
        // max_window values read; Reset the check
        //
        if ((++num_values >= max_window) && (num_hit >= min_over))
        {
            printf("It happened!\n");
            memset(over, 0, max_window);
            num_values = 0;
        }
    }

    fclose(fpt);
    system("pause");
}
```

Since you want a ratio of 2/3, that corresponds to `min_over / max_window` values.

I ran this on your commented data sample:

```
Temperature
190.00
190.00
170.00
It happened!
200.00
190.00
100.00
It happened!
100.00
190.00
190.00
It happened!
```

Comment: when I try to compile, it was failed and mentioned that the memset and exceeded were not declared and the int function is not allowed there before "{" token, how could I solve it ya

Comment: @green I just gave you the pieces to your puzzle. They have to be integrated properly into your code. I've edited my solution to make it easier to integrate. The `...` means other stuff of yours goes there.

Comment: @green I was trying to be concise with the answer, but I integrated your code into it to make it extra easy. :)

Comment: thank you!! I tried it too, but if I tried with 1st two data is greater than 180, it will directly shown the message "it happened" even it's just input of two data,hmmm

Comment: @green, if the first two data are > 180, then no matter what the 3rd might be, 2 out of 3 are out of range. But if you want to avoid the specific case of 2 out of 2, then you can put a special check in the code for that, which I just added.

Comment: In the declaration, why you using const int instead of just using int, between I've edited my ques with pics of data and expected output, how could I program it as I want to reset the counter like back to zero so that when 2 out of 3 is detected it will wait for another 2 out of 3, sorry for any inconvenience, thank you very much

Comment: @green, ok that wasn't clear from your original requirements. I use `const int` for values that aren't supposed to change. To do the "reset on match" you would just zero out the `over` array. I will modify the answer accordingly (see the update). Are there any other requirements you haven't mentioned? ;)

Comment: @green, could you please let me know if this is correct? You want to check for at least 2 out of 3 over 180, but ONLY if you've read at least 3 values from the file, AND you want to reset the check after each time it triggers?

Comment: ya it's correct, thanks! Btw what's the purpose of memset(over, 0, max_window); before the while function, I tried hard to understand the overall program but I somehow still don't understand the algorithm behind as a new C learner, could I have more comments in the program? sorry if troubling you, it's okay for now..just perhaps I need to take more time

Comment: All `memset` does is set the `over` array to all 0's. The `while` loop keeps track of consecutive "overages" in the `over` array by setting the next value in `over` to 1 if the temp is over, or 0 otherwise. It wraps around when it gets to the end, so it always knows the last `max_window` "overages". Each time through the `while` loop, those 1's are added up to see if they exceed the `min_over` value. In this case, it's checking for 2 (`min_over`) out of 3 (`max_window`) but you can set these however you wish and check 3 out of 5 or anything else.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50868/discussion-between-green-and-lurker)

Answer (score 1):

There are about a million billion different ways to do this, but you just need to keep track of how many samples exceed the threshold and then do whatever you want to do when you hit that mark.

Let's say, once you find your "2 out of 3" samples that exceed 180 you want to print the list and stop reading from the file:

```
FILE *fpt;
float t;
float samples[3] = {0};             // keep a record of 3 samples
int total = 0, i;
fpt = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

while (fscanf(fpt, "%f", &t) == 1)  // read until there are no more samples
{
    total = 0;   // clear our counter
    samples[2] = samples[1];   // toss out the old 3rd sample
    samples[1] = samples[0];   // and shift them to make room for the
    samples[0] = t;            // one we just read

    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
        if(samples[i] > 180)        // if any are over 180
            total++;                // increment our counter
    if(total == 2) {                // if 2 of the 3 are over 180, we got 2 out of 3
        printf("2 out of 3 samples are greater than 180!\n");
        printf("1: %f\n2: %f\n3:%f\n", samples[2],samples[1],samples[0]);
        break;
    }
}

fclose(fpt);
```

It's not very efficient.. but should be pretty easy to understand.